# If I hibernate my Linux distro (which has an encrypted partition) and store it in a unencrypted swap partition, can an attacker access all my data?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, data-leakage, swap, hibernate

Is it possible? How? Should I encrypt my swap partition? If I don't encrypt it, basically I make encryption in the main partition useless.

Comment: How is the encrypted partition encrypted?

Comment: They can read the LUKS master key from the RAM dump in the (unencrypted) swap partition.